Ubuntu 24.04 - network is unavailable/unreachable
This problem arose when I upgraded to 24.04 prior to the 8/29/2024 .1 release: The upgrade broke the internet connection. This is the bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2055012
Here is the link from this forum:
Internet is not working after upgrading to ubuntu 24.04
My problem is that the fix, as described, is not clear to me (as follows):

/etc/resolv.conf became a broken link, along with
systemd-resolve.service. I needed to remove both of them and write a
new resolv.conf to fix the error.

I assumed that  the broken link is the symbolic link in /etc. Initially I though it should point to resolv.conf instead of stub-resolve.conf So I set the symbolic link at /etc/resolv.conf to /etc/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf.
I used nautilus Wired Settings manager (IPv4) to write nameserver 8.8.8.8 into the file /etc/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf then used nano to check nameserver 8.8.8.8 is in the file and stayed there after rebooting the PC (or reinserting it after rebooting the PC).
I tried writing (as "nameserver") our local DCHP compliant DNS IP address, this did not work either.
In "Wired settings" IPv4 method is "Automatic (DCHP)".
For "removing systemd-resolve.service", I followed this:
https://www.turek.dev/posts/disable-systemd-resolved-cleanly/
and set dnsstublistener=no
I rebooted PC sporadically.
There is no file resolv.conf.old to restore.
UPDATE:
In order to replace the symlink with the real file (resolv.conf), in /etc, I tried:
sudo mv resolv.conf xxx.xxx
then
cp /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf resolv.conf
UPDATE 2:
The contents of the file did not change after copying it (I did check):
nameserver [my local DNS address]

search .

then
ping -n 8.8.8.8
"Network is unreachable".
Ping -n google.com
"Temporary failure in name resolution"

then, in /etc:
ls-l resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 790 Sep 8 18:34 resolv.conf

My Netplan status is "Offline".
resolvectl status says:
Global

Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNA -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS server: [IP of my DNS server]

DNS servers: [Same IP as above]

Link2 (enp0s31f6)

Current Scopes: none
Protocols: DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

DNS Servers [same IP as above]

I have spent several hours and failed thus far. Any good advice much appreciated: If I can get the internet back (as others have clearly been able to do), then I can reinstall systemd-resolved and apply the 24.04 bug fixes. Many thanks for the good advice so far.
Paul
UPDATE 3:
nmcli -p device show

    ===============================================================================
                                  Device details (lo)
    ===============================================================================
    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     lo
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/136
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
    IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
    IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ===============================================================================
                              Device details (enp0s31f6)
    ===============================================================================
    GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.HWADDR:                         C0:25:A5:88:93:F8
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Comment @ bug site:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/2055012  ...After that I've realized that doing sudo apt install systemd-resolved seems to fix the situation better (/etc/resolv.conf is a link again, but now it's not broken). Also, netplan status reported to be offline before and says it's online now. resolvectl status lets you see your dhcp configured dns servers...

David, thanks very much - but can I do a Sudo apt install without internet? Best regards, Paul

I did "nano /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service" and compared its contents to the contents shown here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2492456 and mine has some extra stuff including a bunch of "Restrict" including "RestrictNamespaces=yes" and "RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_NETLLINK AF_INET AF_INET6". However, the above link gives code from 23.04. But if someone posts the code from their 24.04 installation of /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service then I could compare. Thanks.

Please add all and any new information to your original post with proper formatting. What you’ve added in comments is very difficult to read unformatted. Additionally, Askubuntu is a question and answer site. Comments are for others to ask you questions so that you can provide additional information to your original post. This allows others to come up with an answer to your problem.

Please add the output of the following commands to your original post: ls -l /etc/resolv.conf and  resolvectl status

Normally, /etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. To solve your problem, you need to delete this symlink, or any other that you’ve created, and then create a static file, /etc/resolv.conf,  with your nameserver defined in it. After doing this, test it with ping google.com. If this works, then proceed with re-installing systemd-resolved with: sudo apt install systemd-resolved

There is no such file, /etc/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. If you meant, /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, then don’t edit this file. It says so directly in the file to not edit. This file is managed by systemd-resolved.

You write, ping -n 8.8.8.8 "Network is unreachable". This has nothing to do with DNS resolution. This is a network problem. First, make sure your ethernet device has an IP address. Then make sure you can ping your gateway. Then make sure you can ping an IP address on the internet like 8.8.8.8. Once this is working, the next step is to get DNS working.

"This has nothing to do with DNS resolution. This is a network problem." - I have now re-posted this with a different problem description: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1526386/upgraded-to-24-04-ethernet-adaptor-stuck-at-getting-ip-configuration  Its an issue with enp0s31f6getting IP configuration forever, not a physical connectivity issue, please feel free to respond to that post if you are aware of a solution, thanks.
