Wired connection not working on Ubuntu 24.04.1 Fresh install
This is a new computer. A couple of days ago while briefly trying Ubuntu via USB drive, I managed to get a wired connection to work, however today I installed Ubuntu with the same USB drive and configured a wired profile via the network manager GUI (top right corner of the screen) in the same way as two days ago, but the wired network is not configured properly.
I defined the address, subnet mask, gateway address and DNS servers (as I have done previously), but the network icon shows a ? sign and does not connect to the internet.
When I try to ping one of the DNS servers I get ... icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
When I run nmcli device status after disconnecting wifi I get:

DEVICE        TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION  enp4s0
ethernet  connected               newWired    lo            loopback
connected (externally)  lo          wlo1          wifi
unavailable             --          p2p-dev-wlo1  wifi-p2p
unavailable             --

The results of sudo lshw -C network are (details about the wireless network that is working fine):
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller I226-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 04
       serial: d8:43:ae:9f:49:a4
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd  
       autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=6.8.0-41-generic duplex=full firmware=2017:888d  
       ip=133.24.25.167 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:82b00000-82bfffff memory:82c00000-82c03fff

The results of ip addr show are:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group  
       default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:43:ae:9f:49:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
     inet ADDRESS I ENTERED brd OTHER ADDRESS I ENTERED scope global noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d51a:23d9:b3c5:5d26/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default   
       qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:f3:2d:40:3d:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3

The Ethernet controller (lspci  -k) is:
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller
I226-V (rev 04)     Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]
Ethernet Controller I226-V  Kernel driver in use: igc   Kernel modules:
igc

I have tried to provide the information that I thought was relevant, but I admit my ignorance in this. If there is any other information that is relevant, please ask.
I have been researching this for a while, but that only made me painfully aware of how little I know about this. As the computer is new, the Ethernet driver may be an issue although the particular device seems to have had a working Ubuntu driver since Ubuntu 22.04.2.

"...via USB drive, I managed to get a wired connection to work" needs more explanation. What did you actually do? Mostly, a wired connection works out of the box and, initially at least, doesn't need any tinkering. Provide the information using [edit] not in comments.

This might not be your problem and is a problem with '/etc/resolv.conf'  but if it is then there are links here to help resolve it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1526061/ubuntu-24-04-network-is-unavailable-unreachable https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/understanding-etc-resolv-conf-file-in-linux My file (24.04) is as follows: - nameserver 127.0.0.53 {NL}
options edns0 trust-ad {NL}
search . {END}

any fresh Ubuntu install will work when simply plugging in a wired connection via an ethernet cable ...  did your freshly installed machine have wired connectivity before doing any networking config work ?
