Upgraded to 24.04, ethernet adaptor stuck at "getting IP configuration"
I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04 prior to the .1 release of 24.04. In the middle of the upgrade my wired internet connection broke (it is stuck at "getting IP configuration"):
pg@pg-OptiPlex-5090:/lib$ nmcli device

DEVICE     TYPE      STATE                                  CONNECTION

enp0s31f6  ethernet  connecting (getting IP configuration)  Profile 1  
lo         loopback  connected (externally)                 lo   

I cannot ping my local gateway or google.com without "failed to connect" or "Network not available" errors.
It's not a hardware problem. I swapped the ethernet connection with one from a working PC, and the working PC stayed working on internet and the Ubuntu PC remained unconnected. I am guessing it is not a broken ethernet device driver issue since the following says *-network as opposed to: *-network DISABLED:
pg@pg-OptiPlex-5090:~$ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network  
              
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 11
       serial: c0:25:a5:88:93:f8
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.8.0-35-generic duplex=full firmware=0.4-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:123 memory:70900000-7091ffff

Here is another command I ran (note Speed: 1000Mb/s   Duplex: Full  suggesting, I think, that the driver is functional):
pg@pg-OptiPlex-5090:~$ sudo ethtool enp0s31f6

Settings for enp0s31f6:

        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        MDI-X: off (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes

Here is yet another command I ran:
pg@pg-OptiPlex-5090:~$ ip l

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00

2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c0:25:a5:88:93:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

I would be incredibly grateful for any good advice. Thanks, Paul
UPDATE1:
$ sudo netplan status

Online status: offline

DNS address: [my DNS address that I have in settings]

DNS Search: .

1: lo ethernet UNKNOWN/UP (unmanaged)

MAC Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00

Address: 127.0.0.1/8

         ::1/128

2: enp0s31f6 etherhet UP (NetworkManager: NM-c7e65e10-be19-43d7-84da-e00fc7873955

MAC Address: [my Mac address correctly displayed] (Intel Corporation)

DNS Address [the DNS address I entered in wired settings correctly displayed]


$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/*

network:

  version: 2

  ethernets:

    NM-c7e65e10-be19-43d7-84da-e00fc7873955:
      renderer: NetworkManager
      match:
        name: "enp0s31f6"
        macaddress: "[my correct mac address]"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - [the correct DNS server]
      dhcp4: true
      wakeonlan: true
      networkmanager:
        uuid: "c7e65e10-be19-43d7-84da-e00fc7873955"
        name: "Profile 1"
        passthrough:
          ipv4.ignore-auto-dns: "true"
          ipv6.addr-gen-mode: "default"
          ipv6.method: "disabled"
          ipv6.ip6-privacy: "-1"
          proxy._: ""

UPDATE2:
I did the following:
In NetworkManager, "Remove connection profile"
$ sudo nmcli c delete "Profile 1"

$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

In Gnome, clicked "Wired" then went to Wired Settings, settings. My new profile is "Wired connection 1".
In "Identity", I pulled down my mac address and hit "Apply".
I went back into wired settings, ipv4 and left DNS at automatic. I went to ipv6 and hit "Disable" then "Apply".
$ ping -n 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

$ ip -a

1: lo: bla,bla

2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether c0:a5:88:93:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Unfortunately the problem persists.
UPDATE3:
What should the following file look like?
sudo nano /etc.NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
Mine shows the following only:
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

Should the [main] section have "dchp" key? Should it have a "dns" key?
Should there be a [keyfile] section?
Should the [ifupdown] section say "managed=true"?
Should the [device] section show my enp0s31f6?
https://www.networkmanager.dev/docs/api/latest/NetworkManager.conf.html
I would be grateful to see an example file.
ALSO: There is no such file: /etc/network/interfaces
When I created one in nano containing the following, "Wired" disappeared entirely from my Gnome system tray, until I commented out the two lines and re-saved. Then "Wired" reappeared.
auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp

UPDATE4:
I configured network settings to a static IP with the correct subnet mask and gateway:
$ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution.
I tried a couple of dns including 8.8.8.8 and restarted network manager, and the PC itself. The selected dns appeared in /etc/resolv.conf
Pinging the gateway here:
"Destination host unreachable"
However, now this:
$ip a
[it does give my static IP successfully]
Thanks.

Please add the output of sudo netplan status and the output of sudo cat /etc/netplan/*

Have you tried to manual set a static IP address instead of getting one via DHCP? If not, try that.

I have not tried to set a static IP. I am not sure what to set, but I can ask somebody here for a suggestion.

I updated my answer to show you how.

Thanks very much - to clarify, "I don't know what to set" means I don't know what specific IP to use, but I have asked someone and hope to get an answer Monday, and will try it according to your instructions. Thanks again for your help!

I assume you have access to your router. So log in and look at the settings for your DHCP range. It’s most likely 192.168.1.xxx or something like that. Anyway, it’ll define a range that it will issue dynamic IP addresses from. You’ll want to set a static IP address on your computer outside of this range, but within the same subnet. For example, if the range is 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.100, set an IP address anywhere between 192.168.1.101 - 192.168.1.254.

Are you certain you have a link connection to your router? Did you  select the appropriate IP address for your subnet? Is your IP address showing in the output of ip a? If so, then can you ping your gateway? If not, you’ll never be able to get to the internet.

You write, “ Pinging the gateway here: Destination host unreachable”. Yet you say you now have a static IP address assigned. Are you sure you have a cable connected and a link to your gateway through a switch or directly to the router? If you can’t ping the gateway, you won’t be able to reach the internet or upgrade software. If a cable is connected, are the LED lights illuminated on the NIC at both ends? If no lights, have you tried a different cable? Different port?

I suspect that your connection profile has been deleted or corrupted and that you simply need to create a new profile.

Open your System Settings and go to Network Settings:


If a profile does not exist (as shown above), click on the "+" icon to the right of the Wired connection.


Then click the "Add" button in the top-right corner.




If a connection profile already exists, I suggest you delete it and then create a new one. You can either delete it from the settings window or from the command line.

From the Settings Window, click on "Remove Connection Profile..."

From the command line, type sudo nmcli c delete "Profile 1", where "Profile 1" is the name of the profile you want to delete. This can be found on either the Identity tab as "Name" or via the command nmcli -p device show as GENERAL.CONNECTION.




Afterwards, I would restart Network Manager: sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.
Finally, check to see if you have an IP address in the Settings window or on the command line with ip a.

Static IP
If the above doesn't work, then I suggest trying to manually set a static IP. You can do this in the Network Settings window as follows:

Of course, you'll need to change the IP address and Gateway address accordingly for your network. Only you know what subnet you're using on your network and what your Gateway IP address is. But it will be within one of the following classes:

Class A (10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255)
Class B (172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255)
Class C (192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255)

IPv4 Private Address Space and Filtering

Thanks, I set a static IP. Pinging the gateway "destination host unreachable". I am interested in UPDATE3, above. Thanks.

Despite "network unreachable" with static ip, "$ip a" gives the static ip address. Thanks.
